# Add extra color class in leveleplot that covers values ranging from a threshold and above, supressing its extent in the color scale

Tags: raster, r, levelplot

I use levelplot in R to plot two raster stacks with values ranging from 0 to 600, by 20. This results to the first color palette below. However, I observed that I have some very sporadic pixels in my domain with values reaching up to 900. I want to include them to mu palette as well with a separate color, but I don't want the color to take so much space in my palette (as the second palette). How can I include an additional class with values ranging from 600-900, without taking so much space in the color ramp (denote it as >600 in the top of the palette)

[image]

[image]

```
 # 
library("raster")
library("maps")
library("rgeos")
library("ggplot2")
library("latticeExtra")
library("grid")
library("colorspace")
library("rasterVis")
library("ncdf4")
library("colorRamps")
library("RColorBrewer")
library("maptools")
library("mapdata")
library("rgdal")
library("viridis")
library("rangeBuilder")
library("gridExtra")
#
#
r1 <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
r1[] <- runif(ncell(r1)) * 10
r2 <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
r2[] <- runif(ncell(r1)) * 2.345
r3 <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
r3[] <- runif(ncell(r1)) * -4

months_obs = stack(r1,r2,r3)
months_cord  = stack(r1*2,r2*4,r3*9)
#
p1 = levelplot(months_obs, layout=c(4, 2), margin=T, at=at1, xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL, scales=list(draw=FALSE), 
               col.regions=cr2, par.strip.text=p.strip, main=list(label="Precipitation Climatology [mm/month]", cex=0.7),
               colorkey=list(x=c(title=expression(mm/month), row=3, column=1, vjust=2, rot=90))) 
p1 = p1 + layer(sp.polygons(afr))
p1 = p1 + layer(sp.polygons(africa, lwd=2))
#
p2 = levelplot(months_cord, margin=T, at=at2, xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL, scales=list(draw=FALSE), 
               col.regions=cr3, par.strip.text=p.strip, main=list(label="Precipitation Bias [mm/month]", cex=0.7),
               colorkey=list(x=c(title=expression(mm/month), row=3, column=1, vjust=2, rot=90))) 
p2 = p2 + layer(sp.polygons(afr))
p2 = p2 + layer(sp.polygons(africa, lwd=2))
#
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=1, nrow=2,
             top = textGrob(paste("Precipitation for January (Climatology for 1990-2008)") ,gp=gpar(fontsize=12,font=1)))
#
```

Comment: How are you using `levelplot`? If I call `levelplot` on a raster I get `no applicable method for 'levelplot' applied to an object of class "c('RasterStack', 'Raster', 'RasterStackBrick', 'BasicRaster')"`

Comment: Please consider adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You need to include the packages you are using - looks like raster, rasterVis and grid - but maybe more?

Comment: Thank you for the notice! The script is long, so I have included all the packages used.

Comment: I receive an error running your code, when trying to create `p1`: `object 'p.strip' not found`. Please try to further reduce your example *so it only contains code relevant to your question*.

Answer (score 2):

Your script indicates that you're trying to use the `at` argument, which is the answer here, but its unclear what objects `at1` and `at2` refer to, so you might have mis-defined them. `at` works like the `breaks` in `ggplot2::scale_*()` functions, if those are familiar to you. So, for your specific case,

```
rasterVis::levelplot(months_obs, at = c(seq(0, 600, 20), 900))
```

should do the trick. Note that the following does not work correctly:

```
rasterVis::levelplot(months_obs, colorkey = list(at = c(seq(0, 600, 20), 900)))
```

this will manipulate the legend but not the plotted data. Note also that your `col.regions` argument should be at least `length(at) - 1`, e.g. compare

```
levelplot(month_obs, at = c(seq(0, 600, 20), 900),
      col.regions = c(viridisLite::viridis(30), '#ffb6c1'))
```

with

```
levelplot(month_obs, at = c(seq(0, 600, 20), 900),
      col.regions = c(viridisLite::viridis(29), '#ffb6c1'))
```

**Edit:** Ah, I see you want to alter the internal colour divisions in the legend. `levelplot` seems designed to avoid this unless you set `colorkey=FALSE` and feed in a totally custom key, defined from scratch using the documentation for `key` in `lattice::xyplot` which is pretty opaque. I would suggest that this is a) more trouble than its worth and b) perhaps not the best design choice anyway. IMO it should be apparent that the final colour covers a larger range of values than the others do.

The closest I can get easily is a `ggplot2()` solution, but this would require that you adjust your whole plotting workflow into that paradigm, which may not be desirable. Still,

```
library(ggplot2)

# just some DEM data I have for an example
data('heronvale_covariates', package = 'dsmartr')
# convert raster to df
hvc <- as.data.frame(heronvale_covariates[[1]], xy = TRUE)
# factorise the actual raster values with e.g.
hvc$plotthis <- cut(hvc[, 3], breaks = c(seq(0, 50, 10), 140))
# format factor labels for maximum fussiness...
levels(hvc$plotthis) <- gsub('^\\(', '', levels(hvc$plotthis))
levels(hvc$plotthis) <- gsub(']$',   '', levels(hvc$plotthis))
levels(hvc$plotthis) <- gsub(',', ' - ', levels(hvc$plotthis))

# assign a colour for each category
pal_custom <- c(viridisLite::viridis(5), '#ffb6c1')

ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = na.omit(hvc), aes(x = x, y = y, fill = plotthis)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal_custom, drop = FALSE, na.value = NA) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
  labs(fill = 'Elevation') +
  coord_sf(crs = 3577)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but still the values from 600 to 900 extent to almost half of the scale. How could I suppress this extent?

Comment: yep, realised as soon as I posted - still trawling through docs, will edit. Although there's a solid argument that you shouldn't do this, for maximum clarity...